# Extracting DCT coefficients from mpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am new to FFMPEG. I know how to extract key frames,
but now I want to extract DC coefficients of those I frames.

Could you help in writing the correct syntax of FFMPEG command to get DC coefficients?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg command will not give you dc coefficients. It is not designed to give you syntactic elements of video. You will have to download ffmpeg source.Change the source code for the decoder of your choice to write the elements [DC coefficients from the I frame] and dump it to a file.

Comment: i have made a tiny c++ program and i managed to extract the frame types for mpeg-1/2 formats, but iam still having a problem with the decoding process, i donot know how to decode mpeg-4 file ? the sample i got define some constants INBUF_SIZE 4096 , is it the same values for mpeg-4 ?

Comment: @Saddam, that is non trivial. Why dont you use ffmpeg which already has the whole decoder and is available in source? Just put the fwrite in the right places and you have any parameter you want from the bitstream.

Comment: yes the program i made using FFMPEG libraries and i have found  some sample decoding on internet , but i still cannot decode MPEG - files rather some MPEG-2 files , i donot know why ? could you plz explain how to use fwrite ?